# F1 score in pandas dataframe row-wise comparisons

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I hope someone can help me with this - I am new to this. I wish have a dataframe that is 9  x 5000, first rows looking like this:

```
  Article IDInclude 0.3     1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.9 2.0 2.3 2.5 3.2 

0   4514313 False   False   NaN NaN 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
1   4514313 False   False   NaN NaN 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 NaN 0.0 1.0
2   8420104 True    True    0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 NaN 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0
```

I would like to find the F1 score. Each "Article ID" appears two times in the dataset, one by each coder, and I would like to compare the rows where the Article ID is the same. Is there any way to make the first appearing Article ID y_true and the second time it appears y_pred.

```
sklearn.metrics.f1_score(y_true, y_pred, *, labels=None, pos_label=1, average='binary', sample_weight=None, zero_division='warn')


Thank you!
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Article ID')
df_true = grouped.first().reset_index()
df_pred = grouped.last().reset_index()
```